# How to upgrade Ubuntu Software Center to the latest version

Tags: software-center

I want to update my Ubuntu Software Center to the latest version. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update manager will always update the softwares to the version meant for your distro not any other (i.e for 11.04 not 11.10). if you do want to try 11.10 version of ubuntu soft center go to this site https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center (this is the official ppa for ubuntu soft center) download the latest stable release and try to install it(at your own risk)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to update it through the default update program. It will install the latest version for sure.

Comment: ooh , forgot to mention that I don't want to update my Ubuntu to 11.10 , I

Comment: Then I Am Not Sure That You Will Be Able To. I Think The New Software Center Is Gnome 3 Dependent. Anyway I Am Not An Expert So You'd Better Wait For A Better Answer.

Comment: you are always welcome.